# How to make each record in COPY command occupy a single line?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running into problems because my `COPY` command is splitting records with newlines across multiple lines, causing problems for further processing.  Here is my command, what can I do to make every record be just a single line in the output?

```
COPY {table} TO STDOUT WITH CSV
HEADER
DELIMITER '|'
NULL ''
QUOTE '"'
ESCAPE '\\'
FORCE QUOTE *
```

My current output looks something like this:

```
|"val"|"val"|"val


otherstuff"|||
|"val"|...etc...
```

Comment: How do you want the newlines that are in the database to be represented in the CSV output?

Comment: Just a blank space ' ' would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\copy` with a select query and use a string replacement function to substitute newlines with spaces.  You'll need to manually select all the columns you want to output.

Example:

```
\copy (select column_a, column_b, column_c, regexp_replace(column_with_newlines, '[\n\r]+', ' ') as column_with_newlines from table) to STDOUT;
```